# System hangs when writing files to NFS share

Tags: 18.04, mount, nfs

I have an unusual problem with my NFS configuration.
I'm building a NAS, so I tried setting up FreeNAS on VirtualBox. It all works fine, I can read/write to the share with sshfs without any problems. The problem is with NFS. I can read from it without any problems, but the moment I start writing to it, the whole system pretty much hangs. I can't open new file explorer windows, can't click anything on the window I started the file transfer on. Overall, I can't do anything until the file transfer is complete. When that happens, I can freely use the system again.
Is there any way I can fix this?

My OS is Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS running KDE Plasma. I also tried it on my laptop running Ubuntu 20.04. The issue still exists there.
Also, it doesn't matter if I start the file transfer from terminal or dolphin. The system always hangs.